# Mobile Application as Two Versions based on the same structure

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Im currently developing an application for mobile phones (smart phones). My mind have picked up the path of distrubuting the app in two different versions. One that are free but do have adds and banners in it, and one that you have to pay for that doesn't have the adds or the banners.

So basically, both of the versions are based on the same program but the main difference is that they either are bound of ads or not. This is clear to me and I have no questions acording this idea. **But..**

I found it pretty tricky to organize my projects for my application, to be clear, Im developing the application for Windows Phone 7, Android and also iOS. For the moment Im trying to organize my Windows Phone 7 project/projects in Visual Studio, but Im quite confused in which way I should have the projects saved.

I mean, if I for example have two different projects in Visual Studio, one that have ads and one that don't. If i need to fix something in the application I need to make the changes in both of the projects, and Im sure that this isn't the right way to handle these things. So if someone have any experience in having your application in two different version but with the same functionality (except of the ads) feel free to explain to me how you usually handle these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better idea its add trial version of your application. Then you can have one application and add sth like:

```
if(isTrial)
{
 //show banner
}
```

in windows phone you must use

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace;
```

and use properties of this namespace.

Comment: Wow, I had forgot about the whole trial version thing. Thanks.

Comment: You welcome :) This namespace give a lot of capabilities. So Visual studio also gives option for run application on Trial mode.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally have a single project, with a single set of files, and just use conditional compilation (`#ifdef`...`#endif`) to strip out the ad-related code. I would make two targets (four counting the two debug targets), one with the compile-time flag, one without, and build whichever I need at the time.